# Fitting a custom COBRApy model to data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, lmfit

I am trying to fit a model constructed using the `cobra` package to some data using `curve_fit` or `limfit` and I encounter a ValueError as shown in the minimal example below:

Here is a minimal cobra model construction:

```
import cobra
from cobra import Model, Reaction, Metabolite

#Create some metabolites
mc_e = Metabolite(
    'c_e',
    name = 'carbon source',
    compartment = 'e'
)
mc_c = Metabolite(
    'c_c',
    name = 'carbon source',
    compartment = 'c'
)

#Create some reactions
rxc = Reaction('C')
rxc.name = 'carbon uptake'
rxc.lower_bound = 0.
rxc.upper_bound = 1000.

rxd = Reaction('D')
rxd.name = 'carbon demand'
rxd.lower_bound = 0.
rxd.upper_bound = 1000.

#add metabolites to the reactions
rxc.add_metabolites({
    mc_e   : -1,
    mc_c   :  1
})
rxd.add_metabolites({
    mc_c   : -1,
})

#create a model
model = Model('test_model')

#add the reactions to the model
model.add_reactions([rxc, rxd])

# create and add exchange reactions to the model
model.add_boundary(model.metabolites.get_by_id("c_e") , type="exchange", ub=0); #only inflow (-)
```

Here is a simple function that modifies the above model with some input parameters, runs it, and returns one of the fluxes as output:

```
def fmodel (cmax, sc): # fitting model
    global model
    with model as model:
        rxc.add_metabolites({
        mc_e   : -1,
        mc_c   :  sc
        }, combine=False)
        rxc.bounds = (0, cmax) 
        model.objective = 'C'
        # Run FBA with the model
        solution = model.optimize()
        return solution.fluxes['D']
```

If we call the above function with some test parameters it works:

```
fmodel(2, 2) # returns 4.0
```

However, trying to fit the model using `curve_fit()`,

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Provide initial parameters and their bounds
p0 = [1.5]  # initial guess
bounds = ( # lower and upper bounds
    [0], 
    [1000]) 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fmodel, [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], p0, bounds=bounds)
```

produces the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 7
      3 p0 = [1.5]  # initial guess
      4 bounds = ( # lower and upper bounds
      5     [0], 
      6     [1000])  
----> 7 popt, pcov = curve_fit(fmodel, [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], p0, bounds=bounds)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:800, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    797 if 'max_nfev' not in kwargs:
    798     kwargs['max_nfev'] = kwargs.pop('maxfev', None)
--> 800 res = least_squares(func, p0, jac=jac, bounds=bounds, method=method,
    801                     **kwargs)
    803 if not res.success:
    804     raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + res.message)

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py:820, in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    817 if method == 'trf':
    818     x0 = make_strictly_feasible(x0, lb, ub)
--> 820 f0 = fun_wrapped(x0)
    822 if f0.ndim != 1:
    823     raise ValueError("`fun` must return at most 1-d array_like. "
    824                      "f0.shape: {0}".format(f0.shape))

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py:815, in least_squares.<locals>.fun_wrapped(x)
    814 def fun_wrapped(x):
--> 815     return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))

File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:485, in _wrap_func.<locals>.func_wrapped(params)
    484 def func_wrapped(params):
--> 485     return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

Cell In[24], line 8, in fmodel(cmax, sc)
      3 with model as model:
      4     rxc.add_metabolites({
      5     mc_e   : -1,
      6     mc_c   :  sc
      7     }, combine=False)
----> 8     rxc.bounds = (0, cmax) 
      9     model.objective = 'C'
     10     # Run FBA with the model

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cobra/util/context.py:107, in resettable.<locals>.wrapper(self, new_value)
    105 old_value = getattr(self, func.__name__)
    106 # Don't clutter the context with unchanged variables
--> 107 if old_value == new_value:
    108     return
    109 context(partial(func, self, old_value))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This seems to be due to the tendency of the fitting procedures to pass vectorized data to the fit function where it accepts only a scalar. How can I avoid the problem it is causing in this case?

Comment: `cmax` is probably a numpy array. Try printing `cmax` before the bounds setting. You'll probably have to change the bounds to `rxc.bounds = (0, float(cmax))` to convert the 1D array into a single float while still allowing you to call it as you do in the example (you wouldn't be able to if you did `cmax[0]`).

Comment: @jared Printing was a good idea, thanks! It seems that curve_fit is passing the whole independent data list at once: [1, 2, 3]. I guess I'll write a wrapper function to handle the array input and return an array of outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `curve_fit()` passes the entire independent variable data array as  `cmax` along with a scalar fit parameter as `sc` in each call of the model function. So, I renamed the original fit model to `fmodel_single` and defined the wrapper below to handle the input array and return an array of outputs:

```
def fmodel(cmax, sc):
    # This function applies fmodel_single to each element of cmax and sc
    return np.array([fmodel_single(c, sc) for c in cmax])
```

Now `curve_fit` calling the wrapper function works successfully. Thanks to @jared for debug suggestion!

Comment: Apparently `fmodel = np.vectorize(fmodel_single)` causes `lmfit.Model()` to issue an error saying `varargs '*args' is not supported`, so the wrapper has to be defined with explicit arguments.